# Copy a file list as text from Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Is there a quick way to copy a list of filenames as text into the clipboard from [Windows Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Explorer)?

I can do it from the command prompt with `dir > filenames.txt`, but I am looking for something along the lines of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

In Windows 7 and later, this will do the trick for you

- Select the file/files.
- Hold the shift key and then right-click on the selected file/files.
- You will see *Copy as Path*. Click that.
- Open a [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) file and paste and you will be good to go.

The menu item *Copy as Path* is not available in Windows XP.

Comment: Once you paste into notepad++ for example you can eliminate the directories to get just the files names by holding Alt, selecting the part before the filenames and hitting Delete.

Comment: Also using notepad++, do a replace and select regular expression at the bottom for find what: (.+)\\(\S+)\.(\w+)?(")   and for Replace with: $2.$3

Comment: Yes using the regex find and replace is very good but that regular expression @Westrock is not going to work as you are missing a \ and it wont work on paths with spaces

Comment: Thank you @crowie for pointing that out. The example I was working on probably didn't have spaces. Try this for find: `(.+)\\([^\\]+)\.(\w+)"$` and then use `$2.$3` for replace to get just the file name itself.

Comment: I didn't know this shortcut, thanks ! Another solution is to use StExBar from http://tools.stefankueng.com/StExBar.html, which have also some other useful features.

Comment: @AdamBruss I always wondered if there was a way to highlight/copy/paste/delete vertically.  Thanks for showing us how by holding `Alt` and dragging mouse in `notepad++` Very easy and no need to use find/replace to "clean up" file path; +1

Comment: I am trying to export a list of all the image names in a folder of over 17,000 items where the size is not standard (250x250). The process of shift + right click is working, but only if I select 10 files or less at a time, otherwise it tries to open them. 
Using Windows 10 64. Any ideas?  Probably best to ask a new question though I guess.

Comment: When in notepad, you'll get complete path, to remove it just SELECT the path before start of any file name then press Ctrl+H, the SELECTED path will automatically be filled  in "Find what" text input now do not enter any this in "replace with" input box and just click on "Replace All" button... all paths will be removed...

Comment: The option "Copy as Path" is still available in Windows 10. Great :)

Comment: Note that after highlighting your files, the file that you actually right-click on becomes the FIRST filename in your clipboard. It then goes down the list and loops back around. For example, if your files are named 1,2,3,4,5, and you highlight all files, but actually right-click on file 3, your file list will be 3,4,5,1,2.

Answer (score 7):

If you paste the listing into your word processor instead of Notepad,
(since each file name is in quotation marks with the full path name), you can highlight all the stuff you don't want on the first file, then use **Find and Replace** to replace every occurrence of that with nothing.  Same with the ending quote (").

It makes a nice clean list of file names.

Comment: this is so undervoted, this saves so much time, so I up voted

Comment: Also a neat option is VS Code. 
Select the unwanted path, Ctrl-Shift-L to select all, Delete.